# Why does web worker performance sharply decline after 30 seconds?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, performance, google-chrome, web-worker

I'm trying to improve the performance of a script when executed in a web worker. It's designed to parse large text files in the browser without crashing. Everything works pretty well, but I notice a severe difference in performance for large files when using a web worker.

So I conducted a simple experiment. I ran the script on the same input twice. The first run executed the script in the main thread of the page (no web workers). Naturally, this causes the page to freeze and become unresponsive. For the second run, I executed the script in a web worker.

- [Script being executed](https://github.com/mholt/jquery.parse/blob/version3/papaparse.js)
- [Test runner page](https://github.com/mholt/jquery.parse/tree/version3/player)

For small files in this experiment (< ~100 MB), the performance difference is negligible. However, on large files, parsing takes about 20x longer in the worker thread:

[image: Performance of both scenarios on same graph]

The blue line is expected. It should only take about 11 seconds to parse the file, and the performance is fairly steady:

[image: Performance of script without web worker]

The red line is the performance inside the web worker. It is much more surprising:

[image: Performance of script in web worker]

The jagged line for the first 30 seconds is normal (the jag is caused by the slight delay in sending the results to the main thread after every chunk of the file is parsed). However, parsing slows down rather abruptly at 30 seconds. (Note that I'm only ever using a single web worker for the job; never more than one worker thread at a time.)

I've confirmed that the delay is *not* in sending the results to the main thread with `postMessage()`. The slowdown is in [the tight loop](https://github.com/mholt/jquery.parse/blob/version3/papaparse.js#L873) of the parser, which is entirely synchronous. For reasons I can't explain, that loop is drastically slowed down and it gets slower with time after 30 seconds.

But this only happens in a web worker. Running the same code in the main thread, as you've seen above, runs very smoothly and quickly.

Why is this happening? What can I do to improve performance? (I don't expect anyone to fully understand all 1,200+ lines of code in that file. If you do, that's awesome, but I get the feeling this is more related to web workers than my code, since it runs fine in the main thread.)

*System: I'm running Chrome 35 on Mac OS 10.9.4 with 16 GB memory; quad-core 2.7 GHz Intel Core i7 with 256 KB L2 cache (per core) and L3 Cache of 6 MB. The file chunks are about 10 MB in size.*

**Update:** Just tried it on Firefox 30 and it did *not* experience the same slowdown in a worker thread (but it was slower than Chrome when run in the main thread). However, trying the same experiment with an even larger file (about 1 GB) yielded significant slowdown after about 35-40 seconds (it seems).

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing with a simple i=i+1 loop, printing a message every 1 million iterations. The slowdown begins after roughly 20 seconds in Chrome and 12 seconds in Firefox. What is this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Tyler Ault suggested one possibility on Google+](https://plus.google.com/+MatthewHolt/posts/BPuXy3rYc58) that turned out to be very helpful.

He speculated that using `FileReaderSync` in the worker thread (instead of the plain ol' async `FileReader`) was not providing an opportunity for garbage collection to happen.

Changing the worker thread to use `FileReader` asynchronously (which intuitively seems like a performance step *backwards*) accelerated the process back up to just 37 seconds, right where I would expect it to be.

I haven't heard back from Tyler yet and I'm not entirely sure I understand why garbage collection would be the culprit, but something about `FileReaderSync` was *drastically* slowing down the code.

Comment: So I am having the same issue but my garbage collection isn't happening due to a promise chain not allowing the heap memory to be recovered.  Using snapshots I can see the fileReader slows down right when the heap maxes out and then crawls along waiting for the garbage collector to free up more space.

Comment: Maybe garbage collection can only happen once you return to the event loop.

Comment: @Matt Did you ever figure out what was causing this? Why would FileReaderSync or the GC function differently in a web worker than in the main thread?

Answer (score 2):

What hardware are you running on? You may be running into cache thrashing problems with your CPU. For example if the CPU cache is 1MB per core (just an example) and you start trying to work with data continually replacing the cache (cache misses) then you will suffer slow downs - this is quite common with MT systems. This is common in IO transfers too. Also these systems tend to have some OS overheads for the thread contexts as well. So if lots of threads are being spawned you may be spending more time managing the contexts than the thread is 'doing work'. I haven't yet looked at your code, so I could be way off - but my guess is on the memory issue just due to what your application is doing. :)

Oh. How to fix. Try making the blocks of execution small single chunks that match the hardware. Minimize the amount of threads in use at once - try to keep them 2-3x the amount of cores you have in the hardware (this really depends what sort of hw you have). Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for these ideas. Added system specs to my question. Decreasing the chunk size is an interesting idea; I tried it with 2 MB chunks instead of 10 MB chunks and still noticed a significant speed decrease for those last million rows (about 30 seconds in again). And it's only ever running one web worker (also clarified in my question). So it appears we still need to find an explanation, unfortunately.